# Apple Mach-O Linker Error implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I got this weird error when i tried to run my application. I have been running my application many times and it worked fine. After i added an identifier to one of the segues this error occurred. When i clicked on the segue the xcode got all laggy and i might have placed the identifier in the wrong place or either deleted something i shouldn't have. When i clicked on the segue in the name there was main.m or main.h cant remember which. I mistaken it for the identifier and tried to delete it so i could name the identifier. After the lag disappeared so did that option. Now i dont know what to do.

Error message:

```
Ld /Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-    empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MatrixGame.app/MatrixGame normal x86_64
cd /Users/life/Desktop/MatrixGame
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Intermediates/MatrixGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MatrixGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MatrixGame.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Intermediates/MatrixGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MatrixGame.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MatrixGame_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/life/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MatrixGame-empjzfoeajzkidevdewazcmxapsv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MatrixGame.app/MatrixGame

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new .m file to your project, name it as main

And add the following code to it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Also in your project the info.plist is also missing, so you need to add a new one.

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually i just checked and my main is still there, the problem was that from the lag where i thought i clicked on the segue i somehow clicked on the main.m and renamed it. I named it back to main.m and it works. Thanks for the quick response. Your answer made me know in which direction to look